# How do we create resource satellite assemblies

Tags: .net, localization

I have an assembly which uses resx files to store all of the display strings.  I now want to create a satellite assembly that contains the french versions of the strings.

Can this be done in VS?  Do I just create a new assembly, name it correctly and include the localized versions of the resx file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the new resource file with the correct naming to the *existing* project, and VS will create the satellite assemblies.

Naming is *filename*.*locale*.resx. Where *filename* matches the base assembly, and *locale* is the normal locale naming string. E.g. "en" for generic English, "en-gb" for English and "en-us" for American (or, for those on the left side of the Atlantic: generic English, British English and American English respectively).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start>Programs >Visual studio 2010 >visual Studio Tools> visual studio Command Prompt[rigt click and select "run as Administrator" ]

Go To the Exact directory inside solution where the resex lies and type

c:..\yourAppname[e.g]App_localresources>al /t:lib /embed:ucCreditNote.ascx.[culture Extention eg. en-US].resx /culture:[culture Extention eg. en-US] /out:bts.resources.dll