# Resource file version control

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I'm doing .NET Localization with resource files and I encountered with following problem:

I want to provide kind of translation version control. When somebody will change default language version - translator will know what to retranslate.

Resource file is xml and I can to add custom attribute for storing version, but maybe somebody knows better mechanisms for provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one day of searching I decided to use tool called [Susilizer](http://www.sisulizer.com.). For me it has some pros and cons:

Pros:

- It's track changes in resource files
- I can set my own suggession flags to translation
- I can work with group of files like it's single file
- Easy add languages
- It has filter (so I can sieve fields with changed translation)

Cons:

- It costs expensive, but has 30-days evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: my company builds this product. See [Amanuens](http://amanuens.com) - it's a web application that integrates with your source code repository and alerts translators when you change/add strings in the source language.

Comment: Seems to be good service, but during half-hour I can't register there. I recieving error: "An error occurred during account creation. Please try again in a few minutes."

Comment: @AlexeyAza the issue is now fixed - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

[Statellite Ressource Assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777646/how-do-we-create-resource-satellite-assemblies)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out how satellite assamblies will help me to track what record was changed in default language resource file?